# 1h40 to transfer in Sydney, one booking but can't check baggage through

Tags: layovers, emirates, sydney, qantas, christchurch

We booked a flight from Manila to Christchurch with 1hr 40mins layover at Sydney. Upon booking, the details indicated at Sydney-Christchurch flight, its still Qantas Airways but already operated by Emirates and, the “baggage is not checked in through” I asked the the customer service to clarify what does that mean. She said that upon arrival at sydney, we still need to pick up our baggages & check in again going to Christchurch.

My questions are:

1) I’d like to ask (for those who have already experienced this) if 1hr 40mins is enough from picking up the baggages and checking in again?

2) Are we going to line up now at Emirates & not in Qantas?

3) Do they have different line for checking in, baggage drop & just for transfers?

Please enlighten me. I am bothered by this because we might miss our flight going to Christchurch given the 1hr 40mins layover & checking in the baggages again. Thank you!

Comment: @David: The itineraries look to be exactly the same, but the older question does not have the vital point of _having been told explicitly_ that bags cannot be checked through. So its answer will not apply here.

Comment: Yes the OP here was told the baggage wouldn't interline, but in the previous question the info was that it *should*, not that actually would or did do so. Both questions were on single tickets sold by Qantas, and we don't know how the earlier situation turned out. The answer may not be clear until the OP checks in at Manila. In any event, it's going to be tight time-wise.

Comment: Where did you book this? No through check sounds odd—maybe wrong—unless it was a hacker fare. If you're on the QF flight from Manila to Sydney, they will be willing to check through to EK, [even on separate tickets](https://www.qantas.com/agencyconnect/au/en/policy-and-guidelines/baggage-information/interline-and-through-checked-baggage.html#when-can-my-customers-bags-be-through-checked). If you *do* have to claim and re-check your bag, you will need to pass through Australian immigration and customs twice. There is no special line for that: it is not how the airport was designed to function.

Comment: I can’t find the Emirates check-in deadline, but this looks close to impossible: you would need to deplane, get to immigration, go through immigration, reclaim your bags, go through customs and quarantine, go to the departures area, get to the Emirates check-in desk, and drop your luggage before the check-in/baggage drop deadline. Couldn’t find the time for Ek in SYD, but it’s usually close to one hour. That would make it virtually impossible if on time, completely impossible if there is any delay. Are the two flights really on the same PNR? How/where did you book this?